# How to suppress the `RemovedInDjango40Warning` warnings in a unit test?

Tags: python, django, pycharm, warnings

We are working on a unit test in PyCharm and the test itself is passing now. However, the terminal output contains warning messages in the `RemovedInDjango40Warning` category. As we do not plan to upgrade to Django 4.0 for now, these warnings are verbose and distracting.

We tried including the statement `warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=RemovedInDjango40Warning)`  but it did not suppress the warnings.

So, we wonder how to suppress the `RemovedInDjango40Warning` warnings.

##### Technical Details:

###### Partial source code of the unit test:

```py
from unittest import TestCase

import Django


class TestPocFunctional(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        django.setup()
        return

    def test_all(self):
        from application.poc import PocFunctional
        import warnings
        from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango40Warning
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=RemovedInDjango40Warning)
        
        # ... testing steps
        
        return
```

###### The terminal output of warnings:

```
/data/app-py3/venv3.7/bin/python /var/lib/snapd/snap/pycharm-professional/316/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py --target test_poc.TestPocFunctional 
Testing started at 1:54 PM ...
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest test_poc.TestPocFunctional in /data/app-py3/APPLICATION/tests

/data/app-py3/APPLICATION/eav/models.py:84: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext_lazy() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy().
  value = models.CharField(_(u"value"), db_index=True,
/data/app-py3/APPLICATION/eav/models.py:100: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext_lazy() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy().
  name = models.CharField(_(u"name"), unique=True, max_length=100)
/data/app-py3/APPLICATION/eav/models.py:102: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext_lazy() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy().
  enums = models.ManyToManyField(EnumValue, verbose_name=_(u"enum group"))
/data/app-py3/APPLICATION/eav/models.py:173: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext_lazy() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy().
  (TYPE_TEXT, _(u"Text")),
/data/app-py3/APPLICATION/eav/models.py:174: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext_lazy() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy().
  (TYPE_FLOAT, _(u"Float")),
/data/app-py3/APPLICATION/eav/models.py:175: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext_lazy() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy().
  (TYPE_INT, _(u"Integer")),
/data/app-py3/APPLICATION/eav/models.py:176: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext_lazy() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy().
  (TYPE_DATE, _(u"Date and Time")),
/data/app-py3/APPLICATION/eav/models.py:177: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext_lazy() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy().
  (TYPE_BASICDATE, _(u"Date")),
/data/app-py3/APPLICATION/eav/models.py:178: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext_lazy() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy().
  (TYPE_BOOLEAN, _(u"True / False")),
/data/app-py3/APPLICATION/eav/models.py:179: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext_lazy() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy().
  (TYPE_OBJECT, _(u"Django Object")),
/data/app-py3/APPLICATION/eav/models.py:180: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext_lazy() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy().
  (TYPE_ENUM, _(u"Multiple Choice")),

... more warnings in the same category ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76369107/7903749), we can call the imports at the beginning of the file.

So, our solution looks like the sample below:

```py
from unittest import TestCase

import os
import Django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "application.settings")
django.setup()
from application.poc import PocFunctional


# To suppress the `RemovedInDjango40Warning` warnings in the unit test output
import warnings
from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango40Warning
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=RemovedInDjango40Warning)


class TestPocFunctional(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        django.setup()
        return

    def test_all(self):
        # Deprecated:
        # 
        # from application.poc import PocFunctional
        # import warnings
        # from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango40Warning
        # warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=RemovedInDjango40Warning)
        
        # ... testing steps
        
        return
```